# How to use the same javascript file in a Vue file and a HTML file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a JS file called urlMixin.js.

**urlMixin.js**

```js
export function serverUrl() {
    return 'http://localhost:3000';
}
```

I have a Vue file called Login.vue. I can use the urlMixin.js file in a Vue file by importing it.

**Login.vue**

```js
import {serverUrl} from "./../mixins/urlMixin.js";
    
let url = serverUrl();

export default {

  data() {
    return {
      username: '',
      password: ''
    };
  },
  
  created(){
    axios.post(`${url}/login`)
    .then(resposne =>{
     
     })
     .catch(error =>{
     
     })
  }
}
```

There is a html file, index.html within which I want to use the URL present in urlMixin.js.

**index.html**

```html
<head>
<head>
<body>
  <script src="/src/js/App.js"></script>
  <script src="/src/mixins/urlMixin.js"></script>
  
  <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
           
           App.init();
           var serverURL; 
           
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

I want to import the same URL into the index.html file so that I can use the string returned by the urlMixin.js file and assign it to the variable serverURL. How can I achieve this? Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Use axios.create function
You can give there base-url param and import axios as a vue plugin globally

Comment: Could you please provide the snippet that I could use to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I made axios global in the main.js file. As per the documentation, config defaults can be specified that will be applied to every request.

```js
import Vue from 'vue'

import router from './routes'

import axios from 'axios';

axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://localhost:3000';

window.axios = axios;

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router
})
```